# how to show 0.5 hours for 00:30:00 in PHP with time conversion

Tags: php, date

how to show 0.5 hours for 00:30:00 in php

I want to calculate the percentage of hours.

eg.

```
01:30:00 = 1.5 hours 
01:00:00 = 1 hours
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution only requires some school math after the time has been splitted with [list](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.list.php) and [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php).

```
<?php
$time = "01:30:00";

list($hours,$minutes,$seconds) = explode(":",$time);

$totalHours = $hours + $minutes/60 + $seconds/3600;

echo "total Hours: ".$totalHours;
//total Hours: 1.5
```